# Numpy project array of m X coords and array of n Y coords into mxn list of (X,Y) coords

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

Effectively I want two nested for loops over xs and ys, where each x is paired with each y:

```
xs = [0,1,2]
ys = [2,3]


desiredResult = [[0,2],[1,2],[2,2],[0,3],[1,3],[2,3]]
```

Wondering if there's a nice numpy solution?

Comment: Yes, it seems that thread is the comprehensive discussion on it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pythonic comprehension is probably good enough for this one:

```
coords = [(x,y) for x in xs for y in ys]
```

Answer (score 1):

`itertools.product` would be useful in your case:

```py
from itertools import product
xs = [0,1,2]
ys = [2,3]
print(list(product(xs, ys)))
```

##### Output

```
[(0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 2), (2, 3)]
```

if you are interested only in getting a list and not tuple, you can try code below:

```py
[list(x) for x in product(xs, ys)]
```

##### Output

```
[[0, 2], [0, 3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 2], [2, 3]]
```